# "Enter Parameter Value" input box when using insert SQL code

Tags: sql, ms-access

Any ideas why I am getting an "Enter Parameter Value" input box when running this code?

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTest SELECT * FROM ImportedTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ImportedTable WHERE ImportedTable.[Part No] = tblTest.[Part No])"
```

I am trying to insert rows from ImportedTable into tblTest when there is not already a row with that [Part No] present in tblTest. Thanks!

Comment: first suggestion, do not use '*' - explicitly define the columns instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tblTest` is not mentioned on the `FROM` clause of the `SELECT` statement.

Try this:

```
INSERT
INTO    tblTest
SELECT  *
FROM    importedTable it
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    tblTest tt
        WHERE   tt.[Part No] = it.[Part No]
        )
```